# boundary connect sum of Ganatra-Pardon-Shende

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

In Section 3.4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03427.pdf, Ganatra-Pardon-Shende define the boundary connnect sum of two exact conical Lagrangians in a Liouville domain. In particular, in Figure 10, they explain what is happening to the Legendrians at the boundary in terms of the front projection of the Legendrians.

Question: At the level of Legendrians, can we describe this surgery in terms of the Lagrangian projection of the Legendrians instead?

Is it just forming the Polterovich surgery at the transverse intersection point determined by the Reeb chord? If this is the case, why? For example, is there an easy picture describing the equivalence in dimension 3?

Comment: Here’s what the boundary connect sum is definitely not: use the Reeb chord to push one Lagrangian until it intersects the other, and then Polterovich surgery.  Indeed this has even the wrong topology.  The boundary connect sum should indeed be thought of as a Polterovich surgery “at infinity”.  At some point I think we decided it could be obtained from the actual Polterovich surgery mentioned above by “pushing the unwanted part to infinity” but we never wrote about it.

Comment: @VivekShende One of the authors, awesome! It makes sense that this is not normal Polterovich surgery (I'll have to think about this "pushing away" thing). What I was hoping was slightly different--- In the local Darboux chart, instead of taking the front projection as in your paper, take the Lagrangian projection. There will be a transverse intersection and apply Polterovich surgery to that. After asking the question I found http://people.math.gatech.edu/~etnyre/preprints/papers/LCHsurvey.pdf which in Theorem 5.6 seems to be asserting these are the same, but I don't see why...

Comment: In case I wasn't clear in my post/comment, I'm only asking about the construction of the new boundary, one still has to construct the cobordism as [GPS] do in their paper...